# Convert list to two vectors

Tags: r

I have a list that looks like this:

```
spelling_lut <- list(
  "cra" = "car",
  "yr" = "year",
  "carrt" = "carrot",
  "wi" = "with"
)
```

I want to convert this to two vectors. I can get one of them with `names(spelling_lut)` but if I go spelling_lut[1] I get "car" only.

I built the spelling lut this way just for readability while manually going through many many spelling errors in a text doc and logging a correct spelling. I tried creating two vectors originally but I wanted the incorrect and then correct versions of each word next to each other on the same line in my code (i.e. I'm open to suggestions for a better way of doing this).

In the meantime, is there a way to create a second vector with values "car", "year", "carrot", "with"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`names(spelling_lut)` and `unname(unlist(spelling_lut))`

Answer (score 2):

We can use `stack` to create a `data.frame` of two columns or `vector`s

```
df1 <- stack(spelling_lut)
```